# How to get local ip address in network that I'm currently connected to?

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I know I can use `QNetworkInterface::allAddresses()`, but this returns me also many IPs I don't need at all, for example virtual networks.
And I can't `connectToHost()` and check `localAddress()` of socket, my program will be used in networks separated from internet, so I won't be able to connect to Google DNS / anything reliable.

Is there any way to filter address from list `allAddresses()`, or is there other Qt function I could use?

Comment: First, you need to call allInterfaces(), then filter both on interface nad address lists to find the one you want.  You may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572263/get-current-qnetworkinterface-active-and-connected-to-the-internet

Comment: Yes, there is a bunch of matches and usually that is the case.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the job:

```
auto allNetworkAddresses = QNetworkInterface::allAddresses();
for (const auto& address : allNetworkAddresses)
{
    if (address.protocol() == QAbstractSocket::IPv4Protocol && 
        address != QHostAddress(QHostAddress::LocalHost))
    {
         //use adress in any way needed
    }
}
```